# Suckerfish drop-down onclick

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, suckerfish

On [this page](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/case-studies) in the right column are
four nav items.  The first nav item "The Baltimore Orioles," onmouseover shows 3 sub nav items.

How do I get rid of onmouseover and have it show the 3 sub na only when user clicks?  I added onclick to the script but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the a:hover from the CSS.